# What is the statue Hyakkimaru prays to?

Tags: dororo

Hyakkimaru's mother prays to a statue without a head. What is this statue without a head?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statue that Hyakkimaru's mother prays to is Goddess of Mercy. The Goddess of Mercy statue had a head before Hyakkimaru was born.

**"The Goddess of Mercy statue sacrificed its own head at Hyakkimaru's birth so the child would not lose his head in his father's bargain with the demons."**, 
(Reference - Notes, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dororo_(2019_TV_series))

For more summarized details about the episodes you can refer to following link : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dororo_(2019_TV_series)

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: Please try to include them in the main answer itself, not as a comment. Furthermore, it would be better to use other references as I could not see any citation or reference on where the wiki got this information: The Goddess of Mercy statue sacrificed its own head at Hyakkimaru's birth so the child would not lose his head in his father's bargain with the demons. Citing chapters or episode numbers would be better. To add, if you are including sentences word-per-word from other sources, please indicate so as that would be mistaken as your own and would be considered plagiarizing.

Comment: Sure. Your suggestion is appreciated. Thanks @W.Are

Answer (score 1):

The statue actually is called guanyin goddess. The statue orginal have a head but the goddess protected Hyakkimaru and it cost the statue head blast off. Actually it was just a guess from a youtuber. I'm not sure the explanation is correct but here is a link to the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpnvoKhQ7T4). The explanation start at 4:07.